# Output an array of bytes in hex

Tags: ruby, sockets, hex

I have a stream of bytes in my Ruby-script and I'd like to output the values to the console.

Comment: Hi, I mean any arbitrary sequence of bytes. Be it data from an image or video file or simply bytes that come in through a socket. Output could be like the one from hexedit. E.g. "003C A08F ..." and so forth.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you read your stream in chunks of bytes, then you could use [String#unpack](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/String.html#M001112):

```
while buffer = io.read
  str << buffer.unpack('H*')
end
```